# geth, what happened to --logfile?

Tags: go-ethereum

I just compiled 1.4rc and got this error. I failed at seeing how to use --logfile now, it seems it's been removed but I'm not able to find an alternative.

```
➜  go-ethereum git:(release/1.4) build/bin/geth --logfile
Incorrect Usage.

NAME:
   geth - the go-ethereum command line interface

USAGE:
   geth [options] command [command options] [arguments...]

VERSION:
   1.4.0-rc

COMMANDS:
   import       import a blockchain file
   export       export blockchain into file
   upgradedb    upgrade chainblock database
   removedb     Remove blockchain and state databases
   dump         dump a specific block from storage
   monitor      Geth Monitor: node metrics monitoring and visualization
   account      manage accounts
   wallet       ethereum presale wallet
   makedag      generate ethash dag (for testing)
   gpuinfo      gpuinfo
   gpubench     benchmark GPU
   version      print ethereum version numbers
   init         bootstraps and initialises a new genesis block (JSON)
   console      Geth Console: interactive JavaScript environment
   attach       Geth Console: interactive JavaScript environment (connect to node)
   js           executes the given JavaScript files in the Geth JavaScript VM
   help, h      Shows a list of commands or help for one command

ETHEREUM OPTIONS:
  --datadir "/home/lotso/.ethereum"     Data directory for the databases and keystore
  --keystore                            Directory for the keystore (default = inside the datadir)
  --networkid "1"                       Network identifier (integer, 0=Olympic, 1=Frontier, 2=Morden)
  --olympic                             Olympic network: pre-configured pre-release test network
  --testnet                             Morden network: pre-configured test network with modified starting nonces (replay protection)
  --dev                                 Developer mode: pre-configured private network with several debugging flags
  --genesis                             Insert/overwrite the genesis block (JSON format)
  --identity                            Custom node name
  --fast                                Enable fast syncing through state downloads
  --lightkdf                            Reduce key-derivation RAM & CPU usage at some expense of KDF strength
  --cache "128"                         Megabytes of memory allocated to internal caching (min 16MB / database forced)
  --blockchainversion "3"               Blockchain version (integer)

ACCOUNT OPTIONS:
  --unlock      Comma separated list of accounts to unlock
  --password    Password file to use for non-inteactive password input

API AND CONSOLE OPTIONS:
  --rpc                                                         Enable the HTTP-RPC server
  --rpcaddr "localhost"                                         HTTP-RPC server listening interface
  --rpcport "8545"                                              HTTP-RPC server listening port
  --rpcapi "eth,net,web3"                                       API's offered over the HTTP-RPC interface
  --ws                                                          Enable the WS-RPC server
  --wsaddr "localhost"                                          WS-RPC server listening interface
  --wsport "8546"                                               WS-RPC server listening port
  --wsapi "eth,net,web3"                                        API's offered over the WS-RPC interface
  --wsorigins                                                   Origins from which to accept websockets requests
  --ipcdisable                                                  Disable the IPC-RPC server
  --ipcapi "admin,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" API's offered over the IPC-RPC interface
  --ipcpath "geth.ipc"                                          Filename for IPC socket/pipe within the datadir (explicit paths escape it)
  --rpccorsdomain                                               Comma separated list of domains from which to accept cross origin requests (browser enforced)
  --jspath "."                                                  JavaScript root path for `loadScript` and document root for `admin.httpGet`
  --exec                                                        Execute JavaScript statement (only in combination with console/attach)
  --preload                                                     Comma separated list of JavaScript files to preload into the console

NETWORKING OPTIONS:
  --bootnodes           Comma separated enode URLs for P2P discovery bootstrap
  --port "30303"        Network listening port
  --maxpeers "25"       Maximum number of network peers (network disabled if set to 0)
  --maxpendpeers "0"    Maximum number of pending connection attempts (defaults used if set to 0)
  --nat "any"           NAT port mapping mechanism (any|none|upnp|pmp|extip:<IP>)
  --nodiscover          Disables the peer discovery mechanism (manual peer addition)
  --nodekey             P2P node key file
  --nodekeyhex          P2P node key as hex (for testing)

MINER OPTIONS:
  --mine                        Enable mining
  --minerthreads "4"            Number of CPU threads to use for mining
  --minergpus                   List of GPUs to use for mining (e.g. '0,1' will use the first two GPUs found)
  --autodag                     Enable automatic DAG pregeneration
  --etherbase "0"               Public address for block mining rewards (default = first account created)
  --targetgaslimit "4712388"    Target gas limit sets the artificial target gas floor for the blocks to mine
  --gasprice "20000000000"      Minimal gas price to accept for mining a transactions
  --extradata                   Block extra data set by the miner (default = client version)

GAS PRICE ORACLE OPTIONS:
  --gpomin "20000000000"        Minimum suggested gas price
  --gpomax "500000000000"       Maximum suggested gas price
  --gpofull "80"                Full block threshold for gas price calculation (%)
  --gpobasedown "10"            Suggested gas price base step down ratio (1/1000)
  --gpobaseup "100"             Suggested gas price base step up ratio (1/1000)
  --gpobasecf "110"             Suggested gas price base correction factor (%)

VIRTUAL MACHINE OPTIONS:
  --jitvm               Enable the JIT VM
  --forcejit            Force the JIT VM to take precedence
  --jitcache "64"       Amount of cached JIT VM programs

LOGGING AND DEBUGGING OPTIONS:
  --metrics                     Enable metrics collection and reporting
  --verbosity "3"               Logging verbosity: 0=silent, 1=error, 2=warn, 3=info, 4=core, 5=debug, 6=detail
  --vmodule                     Per-module verbosity: comma-separated list of <pattern>=<level> (e.g. eth/*=6,p2p=5)
  --backtrace ":0"              Request a stack trace at a specific logging statement (e.g. "block.go:271")
  --pprof                       Enable the pprof HTTP server
  --pprofport "6060"            pprof HTTP server listening port
  --memprofilerate "524288"     Turn on memory profiling with the given rate
  --blockprofilerate "0"        Turn on block profiling with the given rate
  --cpuprofile                  Write CPU profile to the given file
  --trace                       Write execution trace to the given file

EXPERIMENTAL OPTIONS:
  --shh         Enable Whisper
  --natspec     Enable NatSpec confirmation notice

MISCELLANEOUS OPTIONS:
  --solc "solc" Solidity compiler command to be used
  --help, -h    show help


flag provided but not defined: -logfile
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We removed it a long time ago. We figured that `geth 2> file` was as easy as `--logfile` without having to maintain a flag.

Comment: Any reason why `geth --jspath "%cd%" --preload "monitor.js" attach http://localhost:8545 2> mined.txt` wouldn't redirect anything to the `mined.txt` file while I see `console.log` output into the console? It only outputs `^C` in the file when I close the command window.

Comment: That is one of the worst answers I have ever seen, without qualification, for removing something as simple as a logging directive.