# How to fix the "Incorrect usage" error when using the Embark framework with geth

Tags: go-ethereum, embark

I'm starting to use Embark framework and at some point, when I try to run an Ethereum node with the following command:

```
geth --datadir="/tmp/embark" --logfile="/tmp/embark.log"   \
  --port 30303 --rpc --rpcport 8101 --rpcaddr localhost    \
  --networkid 75725 --rpccorsdomain "*" --minerthreads "1" \
  --genesis="config/genesis/dev_genesis.json"              \
  --rpcapi "eth,web3" --maxpeers 4                         \
  --password config/password account list
```

an error is generated saying `Incorrect usage`.

This command is generated by the Embark framework.

I don't understand what is triggering the error...
I'm following these insructions: https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework/blob/1.0.2/README.md

Geth version - `1.5.0-unstable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary

Downgrading `geth` back to the stable version instead of using the dev version fixed the issue.

---

## Details

`--logfile`, when this option was available, did not take a parameter. The log file was placed in the data directory. And it was removed.

See [geth, what happened to --logfile?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/geth-what-happened-to-logfile/3230) .

Regarding your `--genesis is deprecated` message, see [geth init, what are the arguments?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/geth-init-what-are-the-arguments).

You are using the Dev version of `geth`. You could try using the non-dev (stable) version version of `geth`. Here is a link to remove the -dev repository and install the stable version of `geth` - https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4a37m9/is_it_a_problem_that_dwarfpool_with_48_of_the/d0x1tql.compact .

Comment: In fact, when I remove the `--logfile` option another error is raised: `--genesis is deprecated. Switch to use '/path/to/file'`. It seems to me that embark is not updated (even if I have the latest version installed) and it doesn't follow geth modifications, but I don't find any info about embark being discontinued... Do you think that could be the problem?